# Why I get chrome launch error, when I export some data with html-to-xslx package in node js

Tags: html, node.js, xlsx

When I try to export data with [html-to-xslx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-xlsx) npm package, this message displayed:

> Error: Failed to launch chrome!
>   [0221/145806.785119:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as
>   root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See
>   https://crbug.com/638180.TROUBLESHOOTING:
>   https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

Answer (score 0):

If we want to lunch chrome with root privilege, we must add --node-sandbox in 'chrome-page-eval' constructor:  `launchOptions: {headless: true, args:['--no-sandbox']}`

Here is a full example:

```
    const conversionFactory = require('html-to-xlsx');
    const chromeEval = require('chrome-page-eval')({ puppeteer, launchOptions: {headless: true, args:['--no-sandbox']} });
    const conversion = conversionFactory({
      extract: chromeEval
    })
```

This way worked for me